# Why is not it possible to use two same-shaped delegate types in a simple assignment?

Tags: .net, casting, delegates

I know how to assign two same-shaped delegate types to each other (using ctor of the assigner delegate). But I want to know why one delegate can not assign to another delegate without any extra effort.(I mean del1 = del2).What .net logic lies behind it?
Consider the following code:

```
delegate void T1(int a, int b);
delegate void T2(int a, int b);
...
T1 t1 = (x,y) => x = 1;
T2 t2 = T2(t1); //Issues Error!


delegate void T1<in T>(T obj);
delegate void T2<in T>(T obj);
...
T1<int> t1 = (x) => x = 1;
T2<int> t2 = t1;//Issues Error!
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Sahand, you questions is very interesting, but I recommend you to put examples of both cases.

Comment: @Oybek what do you mean by both? I just put the case which issues Error. But interestingly,something I didn't know before, Sergey's code works fine. I am confused! :(

Comment: It's ok now. You've done what I asked.

Comment: This question is especially vexing since all the different delegate types in the BCL are mostly obsolete since generics have been added in 2.0.

Comment: @usr I dont get what u mean. I even tried the example with generics. It didnt work too. But interestingly when you try it with Action or Func predefined delegate types it works

Comment: @Sahand, i've updated my answer with answer to your problem. You just need to create new T2, and not cast from T2.

Comment: Your example with `Action<int>` works because *both* are the same type. Just like you can always do `T1 t2 = t1`.

Comment: @Oybek I updated the post, putting two more cases. The interesting thing is that the two last cases are exactly the same except that the last one uses the predefined Action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you receive (at least I do) is not that the type conversion in this situation is not possible but rather, that `T2`  isn’t available in this context. This is because `T2` is a type, and you can’t call a type like a function. To convert one type into another, you have to cast it:

```
T2 t2 = (T2) t1;
```

This however will fail with the error, that the conversion is not possible. Why is that? Because both types are still different. Even if two types are defined identically, they are still different and incompatible types, so you can’t assign one to the other.

Delegates are however a bit special. You can convert compatible functions into typed delegates. This actually happens in very many situations, most prominently when adding event handlers, but is often hidden with syntactic sugar. For example `obj.SomeEvent += HandleSomeEvent` is actually a `obj.SomeEvent += new SomeEventHandler(HandleSomeEvent)`; and that’s already the clue you need here: When creating a new delegate instance, you can pass a compatible function to the constructor, and a new delegate with that function will be created:

```
T1 t1 = (x, y) => x = 1;
T2 t2 = new T2(t1);
```

Comment: tnx mate. Now I got the rationale behind it

Answer (score 0):

If delegates types are the same, then you can assign them. Here is fiddle for that - http://dotnetfiddle.net/18Il3h

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        Action action = Handler1;
        Action action2 = Handler2;

        action = action2;
        action();
    }

    public void Handler1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("handler1");
    }

    public void Handler2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("handler2");
    }

}
```

It compiles and works fine. 'handler2' will be displayed.

**UPDATE1**

You still can create T2 type based on your T1. You can't do cast directly from `T1` to `T2` as they are different types, even with the same signature, but you still can create an instance of T2 based on T1. Here is working fiddle - http://dotnetfiddle.net/P0mvR6

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    delegate void T1(int a, int b);
    delegate void T2(int a, int b);

    public void Main()
    {
        int counter = 0;

        T1 t1 = (x,y) => {
            Console.WriteLine(counter++);
        };
        T2 t2 = new T2(t1); // here you need to create T2, and not to cast it from T1

        t1(1,1); // parameters are not used
        t2(1,1); // parameters are not used
    }
}
```

Comment: you are right, but it doesnt work in more general situations. I update the post to reflect it.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, but if u notice my post I mentioned there that the problem can be solved by instantiating one of the delegate type by another ctor.

Comment: oh, seems i missed it. As I said in the answer you cant cast one type to another if they are not related to each other. It's for all types, not just Delegates. In your example T1 and T2 is different type. The same problem would be if you create class `Base` and two inheritors `Inheritor1`, and `Inheritor2`, then you also couldn't cast `Inheritor1` to `Inheritor2` as types are different

Comment: tnx mate for your answer. I know what u mean, but it is a bit different in case of delegates, u can assign a delegate type to another even type, both different, as poke mentioned.